# I am trying to find the right word for my character

Tags: single-word-requests

A character I am writing about has anger problems. It is revealed that would not even back down from a bear. However, I do not think that anything along the lines of "brave" would be appropriate.

What word can I use to describe my character?

Comment: It would greatly advance your cause if you corrected the spelling and capitalization errors in your question.

Comment: Please see the tag info for help with this sort of question. We need FAR more information.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're looking for a word with more of a negative connotation, I'd suggest:

---

[**Hothead**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/hothead)

A person who is impetuous or easily becomes angry and violent.
*‘a few hotheads urged their comrades to break the police roadblock’*

---

You could also consider synonyms such as:

- reckless
- compulsive
- rash

Answer (score 0):

There are several words that fit generally but with different nuances.

"Pugnacious" and "irascible" fit the lack of control implied by "anger problems," which sounds like bureaucratic gobbledygook.

"Foolhardy," "berserk," and "fearless" are all adjectives denoting extreme bravery although with different connotations. As mentioned, "hothead" may work as a noun as may "berserker" or even "hero," again all with different connotations.

In short, the problem is finding the best word for the occasion rather than lack of choices.

Comment: "Confrontational" is a possibility.